# how to set gridsearchCV to ignore the errors

Tags: machine-learning, python, grid-search

I want to use GridSearchCV in Python for my Logistic Regression model, and i want it to check combinations for every possible setting, but i get an error when there is time for penalty: l1 and solver lbfgs because this solver type is not supported for this penalty. My question is: is there a way to say to the gridserach if some combination isn't posible just go to the next one.

```
parameters = { 
        'penalty'   :   ['l1','l2','elasticnet','none'],
        'solver'    :   ['lbfgs','liblinear','sag','saga']
             }  

clf_A = LogisticRegression(random_state=420)

f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score,pos_label=1)

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf_A,
                        scoring=f1_scorer,
                        param_grid=parameters,
                        cv=5)

grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train,y_train)

clf_A = grid_obj.best_estimator_
```

Comment: AIUI, it already does that by default, with `error_score=np.nan`. Do you get an error?

Comment: yes it says that lbfgs  does not support l1 penalty

Comment: As it should, but `GridSearchCV` should proceed anyway.  I've just tried this with v0.22.2.post1, and the fitting finishes fine: it throws some `FitFailedWarning` warnings (not errors!) together with some `ConvergenceWarning`s, but `cv_results_` is populated (with some `NaN`s when the fitting failed), and `best_estimator_` is populated.

Comment: (and you can hide the warnings if you wish using the warnings package, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463362/10495893)

Comment: it is all working now, i don't know what happend